# Why are neon intrinsics for multiplication, addition slower than operators?

Tags: android, c++, performance, arm, neon

I have written a test app to compare c++ implementation and neon optimized implementation for multiplication of two vectors containing complex numbers.

The neon implementation is ~3x faster than cpp. **(Code 1)**

But if I replace neon intrinsic for multiplication - `vmulq_f32` with multiplication operator `*` to multiply two neon registers, I am getting a ~4x speed.

And then if I also replace neon intrinsic for add/subtract - `vaddq_f32`/`vsubq_f32` with `+`/`-` to add/subtract two neon registers, I am getting a ~5x speed. **(Code 2)**

I don't understand what's going on? Why are neon intrinsics slower than regular operators?

**code 1 (~3x faster than cpp) -**

```
// (a + ib) * (c + id) = (ac - bd) + i(ad + bc)
void complex_mult_neon(
    std::vector<float>& inVec1,
    std::vector<float>& inVec2,
    std::vector<float>& outVec)
{
    float* src1 = &inVec1[0];
    float* src2 = &inVec2[0];
    float* dst = &outVec[0];

    float32x4x2_t reg_s1, reg_s2;
    float32x4_t reg_p1, reg_p2;
    float32x4x2_t reg_r;

    for (auto count = inVec1.size(); count > 0; count -= 8)
    {
        reg_s1 = vld2q_f32(src1);
        src1 += 8;

        reg_s2 = vld2q_f32(src2);
        src2 += 8;

        // ac
        reg_p1 = vmulq_f32(reg_s1.val[0], reg_s2.val[0]);

        // bd
        reg_p2 = vmulq_f32(reg_s1.val[1], reg_s2.val[1]);

        // ac - bd
        reg_r.val[0] = vsubq_f32(reg_p1, reg_p2);

        // ad
        reg_p1 = vmulq_f32(reg_s1.val[0], reg_s2.val[1]);

        // bc
        reg_p2 = vmulq_f32(reg_s1.val[1], reg_s2.val[0]);

        // ad + bc
        reg_r.val[1] = vaddq_f32(reg_p1, reg_p2);

        vst2q_f32(dst, reg_r);
        dst += 8;
    }
}
```

**code 2 (~5x faster than cpp) -**

```
void complex_mult_neon(...)
{
    // same as above ...

    for (auto count = inVec1.size(); count > 0; count -= 8)
    {
        reg_s1 = vld2q_f32(src1);
        src1 += 8;

        reg_s2 = vld2q_f32(src2);
        src2 += 8;

        // ac
        reg_p1 = reg_s1.val[0] * reg_s2.val[0];

        // bd
        reg_p2 = reg_s1.val[1] * reg_s2.val[1];

        // ac - bd
        reg_r.val[0] = reg_p1 - reg_p2;

        // ad
        reg_p1 = reg_s1.val[0] * reg_s2.val[1];

        // bc
        reg_p2 = reg_s1.val[1] * reg_s2.val[0];

        // ad + bc
        reg_r.val[1] = reg_p1 + reg_p2;

        vst2q_f32(dst, reg_r);
        dst += 8;
    }
}
```

**cpp code -**

```
void complex_mult_cpp(
    std::vector<float>& inVec1,
    std::vector<float>& inVec2,
    std::vector<float>& outVec)
{
    float p1, p2;

    for (auto i = 0; i < inVec1.size(); i += 2)
    {
        // ac
        p1 = inVec1[i] * inVec2[i];

        // bd
        p2 = inVec1[i + 1] * inVec2[i + 1];

        // ac - bd
        outVec[i] = p1 - p2;

        // ad
        p1 = inVec1[i] * inVec2[i + 1];

        // bc
        p2 = inVec1[i + 1] * inVec2[i];

        // ad + bc
        outVec[i + 1] = p1 + p2;
    }
}
```

Tools used - clang, ndk 16, Samsung S6 (AT&T)

**EDIT - Adding disassembly as suggested**

So I looked at disassembly for code 1 and code 2 -

Disassembly for code 1 (copied only the relevant portion between `ld2` and `st2`) -

```
      88:   00 89 40 4c     ld2 { v0.4s, v1.4s }, [x8]
      8c:   22 1c a1 4e     mov     v2.16b, v1.16b
      90:   03 1c a0 4e     mov     v3.16b, v0.16b
      94:   e8 07 40 f9     ldr x8, [sp, #8]
      98:   03 55 80 3d     str q3, [x8, #336]
      9c:   02 59 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #352]
      a0:   02 55 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #336]
      a4:   02 5d 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #368]
      a8:   02 59 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #352]
      ac:   02 61 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #384]
; outVec[i] = p1 - p2;
      b0:   02 5d c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #368]
      b4:   02 75 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #464]
      b8:   02 61 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #384]
      bc:   02 79 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #480]
      c0:   e9 2b 40 f9     ldr x9, [sp, #80]
      c4:   29 81 00 91     add x9, x9, #32
      c8:   e9 2b 00 f9     str x9, [sp, #80]
      cc:   e9 27 40 f9     ldr x9, [sp, #72]
      d0:   20 89 40 4c     ld2 { v0.4s, v1.4s }, [x9]
; p1 = inVec1[i] * inVec2[i + 1];
      d4:   22 1c a1 4e     mov     v2.16b, v1.16b
      d8:   03 1c a0 4e     mov     v3.16b, v0.16b
      dc:   03 45 80 3d     str q3, [x8, #272]
      e0:   02 49 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #288]
      e4:   02 45 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #272]
      e8:   02 4d 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #304]
      ec:   02 49 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #288]
      f0:   02 51 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #320]
      f4:   02 4d c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #304]
      f8:   02 6d 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #432]
      fc:   02 51 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #320]
     100:   02 71 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #448]
     104:   e9 27 40 f9     ldr x9, [sp, #72]
     108:   29 81 00 91     add x9, x9, #32
     10c:   e9 27 00 f9     str x9, [sp, #72]
; p2 = inVec1[i + 1] * inVec2[i];
     110:   02 75 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #464]
     114:   03 6d c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #432]
     118:   e2 27 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #144]
     11c:   e3 23 80 3d     str q3, [sp, #128]
     120:   e2 27 c0 3d     ldr q2, [sp, #144]
     124:   e3 23 c0 3d     ldr q3, [sp, #128]
     128:   42 dc 23 6e     fmul    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     12c:   e2 1f 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #112]
     130:   e2 1f c0 3d     ldr q2, [sp, #112]
     134:   e2 0f 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #48]
     138:   02 79 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #480]
     13c:   03 71 c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #448]
     140:   02 39 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #224]
     144:   03 35 80 3d     str q3, [x8, #208]
     148:   02 39 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #224]
; outVec[i + 1] = p1 + p2;
     14c:   03 35 c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #208]
     150:   42 dc 23 6e     fmul    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     154:   02 31 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #192]
     158:   02 31 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #192]
     15c:   e2 0b 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #32]
     160:   e2 0f c0 3d     ldr q2, [sp, #48]
     164:   e3 0b c0 3d     ldr q3, [sp, #32]
     168:   02 2d 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #176]
     16c:   03 29 80 3d     str q3, [x8, #160]
     170:   02 2d c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #176]
     174:   03 29 c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #160]
     178:   42 d4 a3 4e     fsub    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
; for (auto i = 0; i < inVec1.size(); i += 2)
     17c:   02 25 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #144]
     180:   02 25 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #144]
     184:   02 65 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #400]
     188:   02 75 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #464]
; 
     18c:   03 71 c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #448]
     190:   02 21 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #128]
     194:   03 1d 80 3d     str q3, [x8, #112]
     198:   02 21 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #128]
     19c:   03 1d c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #112]
     1a0:   42 dc 23 6e     fmul    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     1a4:   02 19 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #96]
     1a8:   02 19 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #96]
     1ac:   e2 0f 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #48]
     1b0:   02 79 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #480]
     1b4:   03 6d c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #432]
     1b8:   02 15 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #80]
     1bc:   03 11 80 3d     str q3, [x8, #64]
     1c0:   02 15 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #80]
     1c4:   03 11 c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #64]
     1c8:   42 dc 23 6e     fmul    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     1cc:   02 0d 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #48]
     1d0:   02 0d c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #48]
     1d4:   e2 0b 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #32]
     1d8:   e2 0f c0 3d     ldr q2, [sp, #48]
     1dc:   e3 0b c0 3d     ldr q3, [sp, #32]
     1e0:   02 09 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #32]
     1e4:   03 05 80 3d     str q3, [x8, #16]
     1e8:   02 09 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #32]
     1ec:   03 05 c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #16]
     1f0:   42 d4 23 4e     fadd    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     1f4:   02 01 80 3d     str     q2, [x8]
     1f8:   02 01 c0 3d     ldr     q2, [x8]
     1fc:   02 69 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #416]
     200:   02 65 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #400]
     204:   02 3d 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #240]
     208:   02 69 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #416]
     20c:   02 41 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #256]
     210:   e9 23 40 f9     ldr x9, [sp, #64]
     214:   02 3d c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #240]
     218:   03 41 c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #256]
     21c:   40 1c a2 4e     mov     v0.16b, v2.16b
     220:   61 1c a3 4e     mov     v1.16b, v3.16b
     224:   20 89 00 4c     st2 { v0.4s, v1.4s }, [x9]
```

Disassembly for code 2 -

```
      88:   00 89 40 4c     ld2 { v0.4s, v1.4s }, [x8]
      8c:   22 1c a1 4e     mov     v2.16b, v1.16b
      90:   03 1c a0 4e     mov     v3.16b, v0.16b
      94:   e8 07 40 f9     ldr x8, [sp, #8]
      98:   03 11 80 3d     str q3, [x8, #64]
      9c:   02 15 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #80]
      a0:   02 11 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #64]
      a4:   02 19 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #96]
      a8:   02 15 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #80]
      ac:   02 1d 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #112]
; outVec[i] = p1 - p2;
      b0:   02 19 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #96]
      b4:   02 31 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #192]
      b8:   02 1d c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #112]
      bc:   02 35 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #208]
      c0:   e9 2b 40 f9     ldr x9, [sp, #80]
      c4:   29 81 00 91     add x9, x9, #32
      c8:   e9 2b 00 f9     str x9, [sp, #80]
      cc:   e9 27 40 f9     ldr x9, [sp, #72]
      d0:   20 89 40 4c     ld2 { v0.4s, v1.4s }, [x9]
; p1 = inVec1[i] * inVec2[i + 1];
      d4:   22 1c a1 4e     mov     v2.16b, v1.16b
      d8:   03 1c a0 4e     mov     v3.16b, v0.16b
      dc:   e3 27 80 3d     str q3, [sp, #144]
      e0:   02 05 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #16]
      e4:   e2 27 c0 3d     ldr q2, [sp, #144]
      e8:   02 09 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #32]
      ec:   02 05 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #16]
      f0:   02 0d 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #48]
      f4:   02 09 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #32]
      f8:   02 29 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #160]
      fc:   02 0d c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #48]
     100:   02 2d 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #176]
     104:   e9 27 40 f9     ldr x9, [sp, #72]
     108:   29 81 00 91     add x9, x9, #32
     10c:   e9 27 00 f9     str x9, [sp, #72]
; p2 = inVec1[i + 1] * inVec2[i];
     110:   02 31 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #192]
     114:   03 29 c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #160]
     118:   42 dc 23 6e     fmul    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     11c:   e2 0f 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #48]
     120:   02 35 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #208]
     124:   03 2d c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #176]
     128:   42 dc 23 6e     fmul    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     12c:   e2 0b 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #32]
     130:   e2 0f c0 3d     ldr q2, [sp, #48]
     134:   e3 0b c0 3d     ldr q3, [sp, #32]
     138:   42 d4 a3 4e     fsub    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     13c:   02 21 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #128]
     140:   02 31 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #192]
     144:   03 2d c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #176]
     148:   42 dc 23 6e     fmul    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
; outVec[i + 1] = p1 + p2;
     14c:   e2 0f 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #48]
     150:   02 35 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #208]
     154:   03 29 c0 3d     ldr q3, [x8, #160]
     158:   42 dc 23 6e     fmul    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     15c:   e2 0b 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #32]
     160:   e2 0f c0 3d     ldr q2, [sp, #48]
     164:   e3 0b c0 3d     ldr q3, [sp, #32]
     168:   42 d4 23 4e     fadd    v2.4s, v2.4s, v3.4s
     16c:   02 25 80 3d     str q2, [x8, #144]
     170:   02 21 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #128]
     174:   e2 1f 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #112]
     178:   02 25 c0 3d     ldr q2, [x8, #144]
; for (auto i = 0; i < inVec1.size(); i += 2)
     17c:   e2 23 80 3d     str q2, [sp, #128]
     180:   e9 23 40 f9     ldr x9, [sp, #64]
     184:   e2 1f c0 3d     ldr q2, [sp, #112]
     188:   e3 23 c0 3d     ldr q3, [sp, #128]
; 
     18c:   40 1c a2 4e     mov     v0.16b, v2.16b
     190:   61 1c a3 4e     mov     v1.16b, v3.16b
     194:   20 89 00 4c     st2 { v0.4s, v1.4s }, [x9]
```

Disassembly does explain the reason for speed up. Notice how in first code, their are so many (seemingly unnecessary) `ldr` and `str` commands between `fmul` and `fmul`/`fadd`.

**Now the question is why does same compiler produce such poor assembly for code 1? What is the reason for all these unnecessary `ldr` and `str`?**

Comment: Why don't you check the disassembly?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Added disassembly. You can read the update. But the question remains..

Comment: You have tried with -O2 or -O3? else the result is anemic.

Comment: @Surt I tried with -O1, -O2, -O3 . But it did not seem to effect the result. Not sure if I am passing flag incorrectly, or cmake is ignoring it.

Comment: @VinayakGarg hi, have you found out the reason?

Comment: @Zachary: Yes, the disassembly explains the reason. Compilers are known to generate poor assembly code for neon intrinsics. Hence the difference mentioned in the question is most probably compiler bug. However newer versions of compiler quite often contain fixes and improvements in assembly generation for neon code.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the disassembly since you seem to have the same develop environment I have:

---

```
LD2             {V0.4S-V1.4S}, [src1],#0x20
LD2             {V2.4S-V3.4S}, [src2],#0x20
SUB             W8, W8, #8
CMP             W8, #8
FMUL            V4.4S, V3.4S, V1.4S
FNEG            V4.4S, V4.4S
FMLA            V4.4S, V0.4S, V2.4S
FMUL            V5.4S, V2.4S, V1.4S
FMLA            V5.4S, V0.4S, V3.4S
ST2             {V4.4S-V5.4S}, [dst],#0x20
B.GT            loc_4C
```

Both generate the same bad machine codes.

Why don't you post the disassembly of yours? Mine might be slightly different since I had to convert the parameters to simple types. `(float *)`

If your disassembly looks the same, it must be benchmarking failure. There is no other explanation.

---

update:

In this case, rule out everything unnecessary:

Change all arguments to simple `float *` like I did.