# Neon code is little slower than plain C. But,i am expecting 3 to 4x faster with neon. Any suggetion how to improve perfomance?

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, simd, neon

C code:

```
for(unsigned int j=0; j<num_boxes; j++)
{
    loc_del[0] = prior_boxes[0] + loc_del[0]*variances[0] * prior_boxes[2];
    loc_del[1] = prior_boxes[1] + loc_del[1] * variances[0] * prior_boxes[3];
    loc_del[2] = prior_boxes[2] * std::exp(loc_del[2] * variances[1]);
    loc_del[3] = prior_boxes[3] * std::exp(loc_del[3] * variances[1]);

    loc_del[0] = (loc_del[0] - loc_del[2] * 0.5) * width;
    loc_del[1] = (loc_del[1] - loc_del[3] * 0.5) * height;
    loc_del[2] = (loc_del[2] * width )+ loc_del[0];
    loc_del[3] = (loc_del[3]  * height)+ loc_del[1];

    prior_boxes += 4;
    loc_del += 4;
}
```

NEON code:

```
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<for_lmt; j++)
    {
            vloc_del = vld4q_f32(loc_del);
            vprior_boxes = vld4q_f32(prior_boxes);
            ovloc_del = {vmlaq_f32(vprior_boxes.val[0],  vmulq_f32(vloc_del.val[0], var1_32x4), vprior_boxes.val[2]),
                    vmlaq_f32(vprior_boxes.val[1], vmulq_f32(vloc_del.val[1], var1_32x4), vprior_boxes.val[3]),
                    vmulq_f32(vprior_boxes.val[2], vexpq_f32(vmulq_f32(vloc_del.val[2], var2_32x4))),
                    vmulq_f32(vprior_boxes.val[3], vexpq_f32(vmulq_f32(vloc_del.val[3], var2_32x4)))};
           tmp1 = vmlsq_f32(ovloc_del.val[0], ovloc_del.val[2], _0_5_32x4);
           tmp2 = vmlsq_f32(ovloc_del.val[1], ovloc_del.val[3], _0_5_32x4);
           ovloc_del = {vmulq_f32(tmp1, width_32x4), vmulq_f32(tmp2, height_32x4), vmulq_f32(vaddq_f32(ovloc_del.val[2], tmp1), width_32x4), vmulq_f32(vaddq_f32(ovloc_del.val[3], tmp2), height_32x4)};
           vst4q_f32(loc_del, ovloc_del);
           prior_boxes += 16;
           loc_del += 16;
    }
```

I would like to use NEON to parallelize floats multiplications: four float multiplications simultaneously instead of one.

Comment: Two questions: Did you compile with optimisations enabled ? Did you check the generated code to see if the compiler is autovectorising the scalar code already ?

Comment: yes, I have compiled with -O3.

Comment: i didn't checked generated code.

Comment: i will check and update. thanks for your reply

Comment: no i did n't find any vector operations in scalar code. @PaulR

Comment: What CPU model are you testing on?  Cortex-A53 for example?  What actual numbers are you getting?  And what exact compiler / version are you using?  clang 11.0.1?

Comment: CPU model Cortex-A53.with scalar code : 2.24626 (ms)and with cpp+neon:2.34495 (ms)

Comment: compiler g++(gcc version 7.5.0)

Comment: i am verifying  on Jetson Nano

Comment: Neon has no direct `exp` instruction. I think the compiler simply generates very inefficient code. You really should check the disassembly on how the compiler handles it

Comment: Copy-paste exp_ps() from there: http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/neon_mathfun.h Have not tested, but the implementation looks reasonable.

Comment: **exp** function i am using from arm compute library

Comment: As mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095698/why-are-neon-intrinsics-for-multiplication-addition-slower-than-operators?rq=1) i am also seeing same behavior

Comment: You are seeing the same behaviour as the question you've linked meaning tens of LDR/STR to the stack (called reloads)? In that case, you're almost certainly not actually passing `-O3` through to the code. Relevant disassembly or a full compilable example (godbolt.org if possible) would go a long way to helping answer your question.